# Git: Creating an alias for running ruby commands from terminal

Tags: ruby, git, bash

I had the following script in a bash file titled `someCommand`:

```
filename="$1"; day="$2"; month="$3"; message=""$4""

ruby -r "~/someFolder/someClass.rb" -e "someClass.run('$filename', '$day', '$month', '$message')"
```

I now want to convert it to a git alias rather than have it be a bash alias, so I tried:

```
git config --global alias.someCommand 'ruby -r "~/someFolder/someFile" -e "someClass.run($1, $2, $3, $4)"'
```

But I receive the error:

```
Expansion of alias 'someCommand' failed; 'ruby' is not a git command
```

How can I create a git alias to run ruby commands like this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a git alias. You want a `subcommand`.

Name your script `git-somecommand` where `somecommand` would be the name of the command you want `git` to recognize.

So, for `git someCommand` you would name the file `git-someCommand`. Make sure that it is executable and in your `path` and you should be good to go .